ERROR [ExceptionHandler] lru_cache_1.LRUCache is not a constructor TypeError: lru_cache_1.LRUCache is not a constructor
Issue with cache-manager Package in NestJS
I'm working on a NestJS project, and I'm encountering issues with the cache-manager package. Here are the details:
user.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';

@Module({
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService],
  providers: [UserService],
  imports: [CacheModule.register()],
})
export class UserModule {}

user.service.ts

import { ForbiddenException, Inject, Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Profile, Role, User } from '@prisma/client';
import { genSaltSync, hashSync } from 'bcrypt';
import { PrismaService } from '@prisma/prisma.service';
import { JwtPayload } from '@auth/interfaces';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { convertToSecondsUtil } from '@common/utils';
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly prismaService: PrismaService,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}

  async findOne(idOrEmail: string) {
    const user = await this.cacheManager.get<User>(idOrEmail);
    if (!user) {
      const user = this.prismaService.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          OR: [{ id: idOrEmail }, { email: idOrEmail }],
        },
        include: {
          profile: true,
        },
      });
      if (!user) {
        return null;
      }

      await this.cacheManager.set(idOrEmail, user, convertToSecondsUtil(this.configService.get('JWT_EXP')));
      return user;
    }
    return user;
  }

  // Other methods...
}



package.json
{
  "name": "nest-auth",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cache-manager": "^2.2.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.17.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "cache-manager": "^5.7.5",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prisma": "^5.17.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}

I tried to change version of package    "cache-manager": "^4.1.0",
I've got another error
ERROR in ./node_modules/cache-manager/dist/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\miros\Desktop\projects\nest-auth\node_modules\cache-manager\dist\index.js'
 @ ./src/user/user.service.ts 24:24-48
 @ ./src/user/user.module.ts 12:23-48
 @ ./src/app.module.ts 12:22-51
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:21-44

webpack 5.92.1 compiled with 1 error in 472 ms

Please help me fix it

I don't why it works now, but it works! I tried change on older dependancies and it didn't work. Returned to new dependencies. I tried later to run code. And there was no error. Also i add in user.service.ts await before this.prismaService!
I guess it because of  updated dependencies. Also i deleted the folder node_modules and used a command : npm i
